How to Resolve SQLite Network Path Access Issues in UWP Applications
How to access a network file in UWP? Despite enabling the required capabilities, we are still unable to access the SQLite file located on a network path. The SQLite file is being used for reading and writing data in our UWP app.
I already enabled required capabilities like internetClient and privateNetworkClientServer.
Tried to access the SQLite file using a UNC (Universal Naming Convention) path, such as:
\\ServerName\SharedFolder\FileName.sqllite

We though in debug mode we are able to access the network path sqllite file.But once we put on release mode it's not working.

You can add Capabilities like enterpriseAuthentication and broadFileSystemAccess.

Capabilities broadFileSystemAccess was tested, but it did not function.
In our scenario, enterprise authentication is not necessary. Instead of using the Microsoft Store to distribute UWP apps, we utilise our own internal app to do so.

After declaring broadFileSystemAccess, don't forget to enable file permissions in Settings>Privacy&Security>File System. You can try to use filepicker to access network files in release mode to see if you can access them normally.
